# error in SQL syntax near 'and password='''

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, syntax-error

I got trouble making board with PHP It is a part of modifying the writing.
I got this error

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'and password=''' at line 1

I checked for more than 2 hours and search other comments in overflow though, I could not figure it out. can you guys help me to fix it?

```
    mysql_connect('localhost', '***', '***') or die(mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db('personal_info');

    $name = addslashes($name);
    $password = addslashes($password);
    $email = addslashes($email);
    $homepage = addslashes($homepage);
    $subject = addslashes($subject);
    $memo = addslashes($memo);

    $tablename = 'writing';
    $writetime = time();

    $sql = "select number from $tablename where number=$number 
            and password='$password'";
    $result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

    if(mysql_num_rows($result))
    {
        $sql = "update $tablename set
        name = '$name', email = '$email', homepage = '$homepage',
        subject = '$subject', memo = '$memo' where number = $number";
        mysql_query($sql) or die (mysql_error());
        $msg = ' modify successfully';
    }
```

Comment: `$number` ?? Where is it

Answer (score 2):

I guess you need to call `name` instead of `number`

Use below query instead

```
select `number` from $tablename where name='$name' and password='$password'
```

Answer (score 1):

You haven't defined a variable called `$number`, so your SQL looks like this:

```
select number from writing where number= and password='password'
```

Answer (score 1):

Try printing out a failing query before it executes. In this case, it seems that the $number variable is not set so it produces an erroneous query.

Answer (score 0):

Not really an answer as the above answers might solve your problem but you should really use the [MYSQLI API](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) which supports prepared statements